# Problem with discord bot on python SSLError: [SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC]

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, discord.py, pytube

I've been coding a music bot on python that downloads the song with pytube and then it plays it on a voice channel. The problem is download videos of more than 1 hour, with videos of a few minutes there is no problem.
When I do that, this error shows in the console:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: SSLError: [SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2633)
```

I think that the important in on the last line. I think it's problem of my conection or my computer, I don't know if it is related with this, but when I was downloading Genshin Impact, a game, the download constantly stopped because it ocurred an error on the conection while I was using Internet at the same time. Besides that, I don't have ever have problems with connection.
The code is very simple:

```
@bot.command()
async def dwld (ctx):
  url = ctx.message.content.split("$dwld ",1)[1]
  YouTube(url).streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone has this problem, I have solved it by formating my pc and reinstalling everything.